# Convert Hex String into Array and Write it to registry - VBSCript

Tags: vbscript

Here is a string named "Hex" with the value below:

```
43,00,23,00,01
```

Now I'm trying to write it into a binary registry key, for this purpose I need to use the command below:

```
arrValues = Array(1,2,3)
```

I have replaced "1,2,3" with "Hex" but it seems it is not working:

```
arrValues = Array(Hex)
```

It means it can not parse "Hex" as an array so I need to convert it into an array then use it in above command. Can you please tell me How can I do that?

Here is the script I'm using to write a binary value:

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

strComputer = "."

Set objRegistry = GetObject _
    ("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "Software\DownloadManager\FoldersTree\Compressed"
strValueName = "pathW"
arrValues = Array(1,2,3)

errReturn = objRegistry.SetBinaryValue _
    (HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, strValueName, arrValues)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Hex() is a function, so there shouldn't be a string named Hex.
2. Use Split() to parse a string into an array of `strings`.
3. Use a loop to convert hex/base 16 string elements into numbers.

In code:

```
>> WScript.Echo Hex(15)
>> s = "43,00,23,00,01,FF"
>> a = Split(s, ",")
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(a), TypeName(a(0)), Join(a, "-")
>> For i = 0 To UBound(a) : a(i) = CByte("&H" & a(i)) : Next
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(a), TypeName(a(0)), Join(a, "-")
>>
F
Variant() String 43-00-23-00-01-FF
Variant() Byte 67-0-35-0-1-255
```

(For a read arrValues)

**Update wrt comment/edit of question:**

So you didn't do it like I told you:

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

strComputer = "."

Set objRegistry = GetObject _
    ("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "TEMP"
strValueName = "pathW"
arrValues = Split("43,00,23,00,01,FF", ",")
For i = 0 To UBound(arrValues) : arrValues(i) = CByte("&H" & arrValues(i)) : Next

errReturn = objRegistry.SetBinaryValue _
    (HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, strValueName, arrValues)
```

Comment: Hex named string just was an example, your code is just for one pre defined string, but I'm looking for a function which can convert hex strings into array so I can use them in arrValues = Array(String)

Comment: @Stranger -1 means True.

Comment: I have edited my question, now you can see the whole script for writing a binary value, using your script to convert a string into array and using it in arrValues = Array(String) will cause "Typemismatch" error.

Comment: excuse me, I'm not a VBScriptor and I only use it in necessary cases. Your Script is working like a charm. Thank you MAN ;)