# Create binary file in windows registry

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, registry

I am trying create a binary file in windows registry to change the compatibility view settings in IE11. We have some web applications that require certain security settings and I want to make it easy enough for the users to change the settings. I can't just set the settings and lock down IE since the settings are different for each application.

I have tried this solution but did not work. [Convert Hex String into Array and Write it to registry - VBSCript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967459/convert-hex-string-into-array-and-write-it-to-registry-vbscript)

I am running Windows 7 with IE11

Here is the vbs file that I have now. I do not get an error but it also does not write anything to the registry.

```
strHexValue = "41,1f,00,00,53,08,ad,ba,01,00,00,00,38,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,0c,00,00,00,8c,96,3d,03,41,87,d4,01,01,00,00,00,0d,00,6e,00,61,00,76,00,69,00,6d,00,65,00,64,00,69,00,78,00,2e,00,63,00,6f,00,6d,00"

arrValue = Split(strHexValue, ",")
ReDim uBinary(UBound(arrValue))
For i = LBound(arrValue) To UBound(arrValue)
    uBinary(i) = CLng("&h" & arrValue(i))
Next

Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
Set objRegistry = GetObject("Winmgmts:root\default:StdRegProv")
strPath = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\ClearableListData"
strValueToWrite = "UserFilter"
intReturn = objRegistry.SetBinaryValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strPath, strValueToWrite, uBinary)
```

Comment: Wasn't this asked recently and the outcome was the code then wasn't VBScript, this example looks more like VBScript though. If it doesn't error but doesn't do anything it's likely a privilege issue. Are you running the script with elevated permissions?

Comment: @Lankymart Yes I am running the script with admin privileges

Comment: @Lankymart  Also when I create it the binary file manually and export it as a .reg file and run it, it works fine.

Comment: Might be an issue with using WMI, have you tested the WMI call using `wbemtest.exe` *(installed in "%systemroot%\system32\wbem\" on most modern Windows OSs)*?

Comment: Also, have you checked what `intReturn` get’s set to after `SetBinaryValue()` returns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Hex String into Array and Write it to registry - VBSCript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967459/convert-hex-string-into-array-and-write-it-to-registry-vbscript)

Comment: @Lankymart I have tried that solution and it did not work.

Comment: Just saying, *"it did not work"* doesn't help us understand the problem any better, how did it not work? Did it behave the same way as your code or did it raise an error? It must have worked for the OP in the duplicate question or they wouldn't have accepted the answer.

Comment: You have HKCU in the key path.The key path is relative to  HKCU. So it should be `Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\ClearableListData` only.

Comment: @CatCat yeah, think [Kul-tigin has already covered that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53547409/692942).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FYI you don't need administrative privileges to write this setting because it's not a  machine setting. It's just a user setting so the current invoker is also the current user.

Second, you also don't need literal string value `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\` in `strPath`. 
You are already using that constant you defined earlier named `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` as the first parameter in the `.SetBinaryValue` method.

Change `strPath` as follows.

```
strPath = "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\ClearableListData"
```

Rest of your code looks OK but since `.SetBinaryValue` does not implicitly create subkeys in the path, you'll need to make sure that the key you want to write data exists. To do it, put the following line just before you call `objRegistry.SetBinaryValue`.

```
objRegistry.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strPath
```

This will create the key if it doesn't exist, so your `.SetBinaryValue` call can work as expected.

After making these changes, the final version of your code should be something like the following.

```
strHexValue = "41,1f,00,00,53,08,ad,ba,01,00,00,00,38,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,0c,00,00,00,8c,96,3d,03,41,87,d4,01,01,00,00,00,0d,00,6e,00,61,00,76,00,69,00,6d,00,65,00,64,00,69,00,78,00,2e,00,63,00,6f,00,6d,00"

arrValue = Split(strHexValue, ",")
ReDim uBinary(UBound(arrValue))
For i = LBound(arrValue) To UBound(arrValue)
    uBinary(i) = CLng("&h" & arrValue(i))
Next

Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
Set objRegistry = GetObject("Winmgmts:root\default:StdRegProv")
strPath = "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\ClearableListData"
strValueToWrite = "UserFilter"
objRegistry.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strPath
intReturn = objRegistry.SetBinaryValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strPath, strValueToWrite, uBinary)
```

Comment: Should it not be `uBinary(i) = CByte("&h" & arrValue(i))` though, instead of `CLng()`?

Comment: @Lankymart It would be a good practice but doesn't have to be bytes unless there's overflow (values not in the range of 0-255). The array is already an array of variants, so the provider takes care of it. You know, we can't create array of bytes in VBScript in natural ways, without using 3rd parties. This is most likely the reason why the provider accepts an array of variants instead of an array of bytes.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin Thank you for your assistance and detailed explanation. I was struggling with this for a couple days.